# Applying same query plan to other lazyframe

Tags: python-3.x, lazy-evaluation, python-polars

I'm currently exploring polars lazyframe with Python.

**Is there any way to apply the same query plan to another lazyframe?**

E.g. I have lazyframe named `train_travel` with a query plan as follows (this is just an example, the real query plan is more complex than this)
[image: train_travel query plan]

I want to apply the same query plan to another lazyframe called `test_travel`.

I can think of a way to initially concatenate both lazyframe, add a column to indicate which one is which, then separate them after running the query plan. But what I'm looking for is, how to apply the same query plan to many other lazyframes, without concatenating them first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function that takes in a `LazyFrame` and applies the transformations required.